# Google Voice Number Displayed on Phone?

Tags: google-voice

I have Google Voice on my Android (4.0.4 Samsung Galaxy S3) and it is set to make all calls using GV (cause I want the user to see GV number on the caller ID). 
However I encounter this problem: the number that appears on my mobile phone (when dialing out using GV) is some unknown (random?) number, not the number that I'm calling. Say I'm calling 212-333-4444 it shows 617-234-1234. It is in fact calling the right number but what shows is the number that GV is using. The problem is that when I look at the log I can't see who was called nor can I try to recall that number.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is [a bug with the S3 phone.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1742325). The XDA thread doesn't have a solution, but there are some things to try...I just don't know if they'll actually fix the issue. You could try installing a [replacement dialer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dialer&c=apps). If you're rooted, you could try finding an alternative phone.apk (perhaps from the S2). Finally, a custom ROM built on AOSP (like Cyanogenmod) may not have this issue.

Comment: I tried replacing the dialer but that didn't solve the problem. I doubt that I am rooted, but I'm sure that I can be. But where would I find a replacement phone.apk, how would I install it, and might that not cause other problems (after all it has been replaced so that might be for a reason)? Custom ROM - that is a bit beyond me. I am new to Android/smart-phone (1 month).

Comment: Well, if you're not sure if you're rooted, it's extremely unlikely you are (unless you bought it second-hand and it was rooted already, you have to deliberately do something to root your device). XDA Developers (the first link in my answer) is a good source of a lot of things, and you may track down a phone.apk there, but as you're not really familiar with all this stuff, I wouldn't advise it right now. I'd say the same for a custom ROM. That said, if you're technologically inclined, there is a lot you can do if you're willing to tinker.

Comment: Also, the issue is that to make a call appear as if it's coming from your GV number, you're technically calling a Google number set up to transfer the call (You -> Google -> Other Person)...so the number you're seeing isn't a random number, it's one of Google's numbers set up to forward calls on. It appears that the S3 dialer (maybe it's an ICS thing?) isn't storing the destination number, but rather the one that was technically dialed by GV.

Comment: yes, of course that is what it's doing, but that is not what is desired or what it has done on other phones. I wonder whether it is fixed in 4.1.1. I don't have 4.1.1 so I maybe someone who does can chime in.